# Issue in scraping with cheerio

Tags: node.js, screen-scraping, cheerio

I have been trying to scrape 10 websites for a website we are building with links to the original sites, on node.js using cheerio, problem we are getting is that some of the sites have changed which now uses ajax calls to bring their data, my question is how can we get that information, for instance trigger a button click first and then get the DOM.

secondly: same dom structure is not getting me all data, it is retrieving information for one page, but not getting the the elements on another page with identical DOM structure. any help would be appreciated.

Thanks and regards.
**Edit 1: Relevant code**

> ```
> $('#ProductContent').filter(function(){
>                             var price = undefined;
>                             var ukulele = false;
>                             var model = $(this).find('.ProductSubtitle').text().replace(/\n\s*/g,"");
>                             if(model.indexOf(/m/i) != 0){
>                                 var description = $(this).find('.RomanceCopy').text().replace(/\n\s*|\r/g,"");
>                                 .
>                                 .code removed for brevity and the variables present here are populated
>                                 .
>                                 //this children is populated only for one page.
>                                 children =  $(this).find('.SpecsColumn .SpecsTable table tbody').children('tr');
>                                 console.log('children: '+children.length)
>                                 console.log(guitar_url);
>                                 children.each(function(){
>                                     var key = $(this).children('td').first().text();
>                                     var value = $(this).children('td').last().text();
>                                     specs[key] = value;
>                                     console.log(specs); 
>                                 });
> ```

**Edit 2: Cherios Initialization**

> ```
> request(guitar_url,function(error,response,html){
>                     if(!error){
>                         var $ = cheerio.load(html);
>                         $("#content #right-content").filter(function(){..children and other variables are populated inside here....})
>                     }
>  })
> ```

Comment: Show the code of how you retrieve the DOM, and why it is hard for you to *trigger button click*?

Comment: I do not know how to trigger a button click from my server using cheerios, I will post the code by editing my question

Comment: To avoid getting flagged, I suggest removing the site you are scrapping from the question.

Comment: Thanks, I thought you will need to know what site I was having issues with, to understand the code better.

Comment: Could you also show the code, where you initialize the DOM, i.e. download the site and parse it to cheerio.

Comment: Cheerio will only load the source. If you're wanting to interact with the DOM then you'll need to use a headless browser such as [Phantom](http://phantomjs.org/)

Comment: @BenFortune I do not understand you clearly there, It is working for the same site on one of the pages, and 4 other sites. Can you explain in laymen terms why Cheerio would not work?

Comment: Cheerio doesn't load the javascript in the page and you can't interact with it (click etc). Anything that uses javascript on the page is inaccessible, ajax being one of them.

Comment: Yes I understood that after reading through Phantom's documentation. But what about using Cheerio for current site I am working on, since it doesn't have Jquery involved in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the 'tbody' tags solved the problem, once they were removed it started to fetch the data normally for all three sites.

Comment: not bad, took only 4 years for that :) - just kidding

Answer (score 5):

To summarise all the comments you received:

Cheerio is minimalistic DOM reader inspired by jQuery. Its design is focused about reading data, and is not a browser emulator, where you could *click* a button.

Alternative is to use headless browsers like [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) or [CasperJS](http://casperjs.org/).

Those two are outside of Node.js scope, and you may have hard times transmitting the data back and forth from Node.js to headless browser.

If it is important for you to keep inside of Node.js environment, then you can use [JSDOM](https://www.npmjs.org/package/jsdom).

All of them are more *complicated* to use than Cheerio, but if you want to manipulate the DOM, execute JavaScript on the DOM, etc... Then this is your best bet.

Comment: I appreciate your answer and clearing it up and it fits perfectly on some of the sites that I will start working on. However my initial question is still unanswered, why is the children object not being populated for all links that have same DOM structure?

Comment: If it works on X, but not Y, where X == Y, then you just broke the primary law of our universe :) You shall dump the X and Y into some file, and then with diff or another comparison tool find why they differ, then the answer shall be obvious

Comment: Thanks, your answer is very informative but I selected my answer because I thought it might help others with the problem, which might be in the module itself. Anyways would you care to point me in the right direction with JSDOM, I cant find any relevant documentation that talks about mimicking a click on page with it. I have posted a questiona and got 2 down-votes :(